# Android ListView in Fragment doesn't display values

Tags: java, android

I'm making a music app where the UI is seperated in fragments.
It's built on the TabbedActivty project.
So my Problem is:
In MainActivity I'm loading music files from storage into Array.(Thats works fine.)
That Array gets passed into a helper class.
The Fragment then loads that Array(That works too.)
I can set up the Adapter, but the listview just remains empty even though the array has values.
I tried lots of code but nothing worked so far.
But I'm not getting any error messages.

My Main Actvity:

```
package needforbleed.com.music;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    //vars
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private ArrayList<Song> songList;
    private ListView songView;
    private SongAdapter  songAdt;
    Context c;

    //methods
    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(android.app.Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        songList=new ArrayList<Song>();

        getSongList();



        c=this;

        Collections.sort(songList, new Comparator<Song>() {
            public int compare(Song a, Song b) {
                return a.getName().compareTo(b.getName());
            }
        });

        Helper.setSongs(songList);


      /*  for(int x=0;x<songList.size();x++)
        {



        }*/

       /* for(int x=0;x<songList.size();x++) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,songList.get(x).getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();

        }*///I used that loop to check songList for Content. It has content so that's not the error.
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           switch (position)
           {
               case 0:return Player.newInstance(0,"Player");
               case 1:return Artists.newInstance(1,"Artists");
               case 2:return Albums.newInstance(2,"Albums");
               case 3:return Titles.newInstance(3,"Titles");
           }

           return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 4;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Player";
                case 1:
                    return "Artists";
                case 2:
                    return "Albums";
                case 3:
                    return "Titles";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        super.onAttachFragment(fragment);

       /*songView=Helper.getLv();
        songAdt=new SongAdapter(this,songView.getId(),songList);
        songView.setAdapter(songAdt);
    */
    }

    public void getSongList() {
        ContentResolver musicResolver = getContentResolver();
        Uri musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        Cursor musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri, null, null, null, null);

        if(musicCursor!=null && musicCursor.moveToFirst()){
            //get columns
            int titleColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE);

            int idColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID);

            int artistColumn = musicCursor.getColumnIndex(android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST);

           int albumColumn=musicCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
            //add songs to list
            do {
                long thisId = musicCursor.getLong(idColumn);
                String thisTitle = musicCursor.getString(titleColumn);
                String thisArtist = musicCursor.getString(artistColumn);
                String thisAlbum = musicCursor.getString(albumColumn);
                Song s=new Song();
                s.setID(thisId);
                s.setName(thisTitle);
                s.setArtist(thisArtist);
                s.setAlbum(thisAlbum);

                songList.add(s);
            }
            while (musicCursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="needforbleed.com.music.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"

            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_color"
            app:tabTextColor="@color/tab_color"
            app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Fragment Code:

```
package needforbleed.com.music;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Activities that contain this fragment must implement the
 * {@link Titles.OnFragmentInteractionListener} interface
 * to handle interaction events.
 * Use the {@link Titles#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class Titles extends Fragment {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "Number";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "Name";
    private ListView lv;
    private SongAdapter sa;

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private int Number;
    private String Name;


    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public Titles() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment Titles.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static Titles newInstance(int param1, String param2) {
        Titles fragment = new Titles();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            Number = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
            Name = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_titles, container, false);
        lv=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_t);

        sa=new SongAdapter(this.getContext(),lv.getId(),Helper.getSongs());
        lv.setAdapter(sa);


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_titles, container, false);
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p/>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name

        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }
}
```

Fragment XML

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="needforbleed.com.music.Titles">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="523dp"
        android:id="@+id/lv_t"
        android:layout_gravity="left|top"
        android:smoothScrollbar="true" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Helper Class

```
package needforbleed.com.music;

public class Helper {
    private static SongAdapter s;
    private static ArrayList<Song> songs;
    private static ListView lv;

    public static ListView getLv() {
        return lv;
    }

    public static void setLv(ListView lv) {
        lv = lv;
    }

    public static ArrayList<Song> getSongs() {
        return songs;
    }

    public static void setSongs(ArrayList<Song> songs) {
        Helper.songs = songs;
    }

    public static SongAdapter getS() {
        return s;
    }

    public static void setS(SongAdapter s) {
        Helper.s = s;
    }
}
```

Custom Adapter Class

```
package needforbleed.com.music;

public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {

    public SongAdapter(Context context, int listviewid) {
        super(context, listviewid);
    }

    public SongAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Song> tracks) {
        super(context, resource, tracks);
    }

    @Override
    public Song getItem(int position) {
        return super.getItem(position);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;

        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi;
            vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.title_list,parent,false);
        }

        Song p = getItem(position);

        if (p != null) {
            TextView tt1 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.song_title);
            TextView tt2 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.song_artist);
            TextView tt3 = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.song_album);

            if (tt1 != null) {
                tt1.setText(p.getName());
            }

            if (tt2 != null) {
                tt2.setText(p.getArtist());
            }

            if (tt3 != null) {
                tt3.setText(p.getAlbum());
            }
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

title_list xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="songPicked"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_artist"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/song_album"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Color XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#f08320</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#d76e0e</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#f08320</color>
    <color name="tab_color">#ffffff</color>
    <color name="nav_bar">#f08320</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: can you also add the title_list xml?

Comment: Opps, I missed that ! Sorry! I'll edit the question

Comment: you only use the Arraylist of songs in Helper right?

Comment: also post your color xml file

Comment: I'm loading content from media.storage in Mainactivity into an array. That array gets passed into the helper array. That array is then used by the fragment. The array itself has values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `onCreateView` method you return new inflated view.

It should be like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_titles, container, false);
    lv=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.lv_t);

    sa=new SongAdapter(this.getContext(),lv.getId(),Helper.getSongs());
    lv.setAdapter(sa);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked. But i can't reall understand why. Isn't it the same to write "inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_titles, container, false);" ? What is the difference ?

Comment: @Needforbleed each call ```inflate``` creates new view, i.e. when you returned ```inflater.inflate()``` you created new instance of view

Comment: Thank you. Simple and understandable explanation. I marked your answer as teh requested one!

Answer (score 0):

in your on create view in the fragment return `view` instead of

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_titles, container, false);
```